# How do I allocate fixed size two dimensional arrays in a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct _my_struct {
    float first_vector[SOME_NUM][OTHER_NUM];
    float second_vector[SOME_NUM][OTHER_NUM];
    int some_val;
} my_struct;
```

I'd like to do:

```
my_struct * thing = (my_struct *)malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
```

But when I do so and then try to access anything in the vectors, I get a seg fault.

If I instead declare the vectors in the struct as:

```
typedef struct _my_struct {
    float **first_vector;
    float **second_vector;
    int some_val;
} my_struct;
```

and then allocate with:

```
my_struct->first_vector = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * SOME_NUM);
my_struct->second_vector = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * SOME_NUM);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < SOME_NUM; i++){ 
    my_struct->first_vector[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * OTHER_NUM);
    my_struct->second_vector[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * OTHER_NUM);
}
```

Then everything works fine.

Since first and second vector are fixed in size and known at compile time, it seems strange that I have to individually allocate memory for them. Is there a way to declare them in the struct so that I can just malloc a new struct without also allocating memory for each vector separately?

Comment: Is the second code snippet a typo? `mystruct * struct` doesn't make sense.

Comment: no it was just really unclear (struct was supposed to be the name of the variable...) I've updated.

Comment: You fixed one of the typos, but `sizeof my_struct` should by `sizeof(my_struct)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have should be fine.. aside from the funky typedef at the top and odd declaration of `my_struct * struct = malloc...` this small test case works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    float first[10][20];
    float second[10][20];
    int val;
} my_struct;

int main(void) {
    printf("Sizeof mystruct %d\n", sizeof(my_struct));

    my_struct* str = malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    if(!str) {
        printf("Memory allocation error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    str->first[0][0] = 1;
    str->second[1][19] = 15;

    printf("values %f %f\n", str->first[0][0], str->second[1][19]);

    free(str);

    return 0;

}
```

Output is:

```
Sizeof mystruct 1604
values 1.000000 15.000000
```

Additionally, you should not cast the return value of malloc. It can hide important compiler warnings.

Comment: You should check that `str` is not `NULL` before dereferencing (this would be a possible source of OP's segfault)